# Power BI - Adding too many rows in previous year calc

Tags: date, powerbi

Has anyone seen this problem of seeming to add too many rows (and revenue) on the last day of previous year?

[image]

```
Private Revenue = CALCULATE(sum(vw_VisitsDentist[VisitFee]), vw_VisitsDentist[Scheme Type] = "Private")

Private Revenue LY = CALCULATE([Private Revenue], DATEADD('Visit Dentist Dates'[Date], -1, YEAR))

Private Revenue Cumulative = CALCULATE([Private Revenue],
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Visit Dentist Dates'),
        'Visit Dentist Dates'[Date] <= MAX('Visit Dentist Dates'[Date])))

Private Revenue Cumulative LY = CALCULATE([Private Revenue LY],
    FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Visit Dentist Dates'),
        'Visit Dentist Dates'[Date] <= MAX('Visit Dentist Dates'[Date])))
```

[image]